# res not defined NodeJs - ExpressJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, controller, model

Hola muchachos como están, necesito que me saquen de dudas. Eh creado un par de modelos en backend con node, y esta vez no entiendo este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Iniciando el proyecto si puedo listar los usuarios, aún cuando no tengo ninguno.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora les muestro los  codigos utilizados.

User Model

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

User Contorller - List users

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Create user

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque res no esta definido en createUser y si esta definido en ListALl Users

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y cambia las imágenes por el código en formato texto. No todos pueden ver las imágenes y es mucho más rápido poder copiar y y pegar el texto que transcribirlo para crear un [mcve]. Te invito a leer [ask]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Checa quitando el else en el createCtrl y lo que esta dentro lo pones debajo el if statement no dentro ojo. Y ahora viendolo mejor creo que es porque en ese metodo create del controlador si te fijas no estas devolviendo una response como tal trata devolviendo un

```
res.status(201).json(newUser)
```

Comment: Mejor que dar explicaciones es mostrar el código final. En este caso no se puede pues el OP uso imágenes en lugar de texto. Eso hace que la pregunta sea de mala calidad y esto muestra porque mejor no responderlas.